# Throws JMSException errors when connecting to a broker via JMX in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I have a code to connect to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker via the JMX protocol using some kind of login/password authorization

```java
 public static MBeanServerConnection connectBroker(String brokerUrl, String user, String password) {

        QueueConnection connection = null;
        try {
            QueueConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
            connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
            connection.start();
            HashMap env = new HashMap();
            String[] creds = {user, password};
            env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
            JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(BuildGet.JMX_URL),env);

            return connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

And this code gives these errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at jmxClientUIPConsole.BuildGet.connectBroker(BuildGet.java:81)
    at jmxClientUIPConsole.gui.DConsoleFrameController.connectBroker(DConsoleFrameController.java:41)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:867)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:335)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331)
    at jmxClientUIPConsole.BuildGet.connectBroker(BuildGet.java:72)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:865)
    ... 60 more
```

But if you make a method without authorization then everything works:

```java
public static MBeanServerConnection connectBroker(String brokerUrl) {

        QueueConnection connection = null;
        try {
            QueueConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
            connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
            connection.start();
            JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(BuildGet.JMX_URL));

            return connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Here is my `management.xml`:

```xml
<management-context xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
   <connector connector-port="13682" connector-host="192.168.1.135"/>
   <authorisation>
      <allowlist>
         <entry domain="hawtio"/>
      </allowlist>
      <default-access>
         <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq,guest,test"/>
         <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq,guest,test"/>
         <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq,guest,test"/>
         <access method="set*" roles="update,amq,guest,test"/>
         <access method="*" roles="amq,guest,test"/>
      </default-access>
      <role-access>
         <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
            <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq,guest,test"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq,guest,test"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq,guest,test"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="update,amq,guest,test"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq,guest,test"/>
         </match>
      </role-access>
   </authorisation>
</management-context>
```

I pass the login `amq` and password `amq` to the method. Maybe I'm passing the wrong login and password? Why can an error occur when connecting to a broker?

Now the method looks like this:

```
public static MBeanServerConnection connectBroker(String brokerUrl, String user, String password) {
    try {
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap();
        String[] creds = {user, password};
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + brokerUrl + ":13682/jmxrmi"), env);
        return connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But if I leave login and password empty, then for some reason it can connect, although I left these authorization fields empty for the test. Why isn't an error thrown when the field data is empty?

Comment: Can you try passing the same username and password to the ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory too?

`QueueConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory(brokerUrl, user, password);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack-trace indicates that the exception is coming from your invocation of `javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection()` so it doesn't appear to have anything to do with your JMX connection. The exception is being thrown before it even gets to `JMXConnectorFactory.connect()`.

It's important to note that this `connectBroker` method is **leaking** a JMS connection every time it is invoked (assuming it is successful). This is because you create a JMS connection, but you don't close it or return it from the method. I recommend removing the JMS connection from that method entirely as it servers no real purpose.

Comment: if i delete the JMS connection then how do i pass the String brokerUrl parameter to JMXConnectorFactory.connect()?

Comment: Why would you need to pass `brokerUrl` to `JMXConnectorFactory.connect()`? The `brokerUrl` is for the **JMS** connection, not the JMX connection. The URL for ActiveMQ Artemis' core JMS client looks something like `tcp://host:61616`. The URL for a JMX connection looks something like `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://host:1099/jmxrmi`. JMX and JMS are 100% independent. There is no overlap in their protocols and implementations although they can be _used_ alongside each other in certain use-cases.

Comment: I took into account your answer and updated the question

Comment: Your modifications really turn this into a different question. Originally the question was about code & connectivity. Now it's about configuration & security. I recommend you revert your changes and ask a _new_ question. I believe I answered the original question. If you agree please mark it as correct to help other folks who have this same problem in the future. Thanks!